# Sort based on length of an array in elasticsearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

There is a field where there is an array stored. I want to sort the documents based on the array length of that field.

Sample documents

```
document 1 = {
"countryCodes" : ["US","UK","UA","IN"]
}

document 2 ={
"countryCodes" : ["FR","SU","UG","UK","US"]
}
```

So, up on sort, the results should be showing document 2 first and then document 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two options here.

1. Use token count type as multi field in the mapping - This way another field would be stored as mutlti field which has the length of the array . You can learn more about it [here](https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-scripting-sorting).
2. Scripting - The same can be achieved using scripting too .

   {
         "sort": {
           "_script": {
             "script": "doc['countryCodes'].values.size()"
           }
         }
       }

Answer (score 4):

For Elasticsearch 5.6.7 query should look like this:

```
GET index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "sort": {
        "_script": {
            "type" : "number",
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "doc.countryCodes.values.size()"
            },
            "order" : "desc"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would be to also index another field containing the length of the array and then sort on that field.

Another way would be to use [script-based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) and return the length of the array using groovy.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "script": "doc.countryCodes.values.size()"
    }
  }
}
```

Also make sure to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in order for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

For Elasticsearch 6.8 the query should look like this:

```
{
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "sort": {
      "_script": {
         "type": "number",
         "script": "doc.countryCodes.size()",
         "order": "desc"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Elasticsearch 7.6, the only thing that worked for me was a combination of [Kamel Mili's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68833224/4751173) and [Vineeth Mohan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33967007/4751173):

```json
POST /test/_search
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": "doc['countryCodes'].size()",
      "order": "desc"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

If `countryCodes` is a regular text field, you'll need

```json
      "script": "doc['countryCodes.keyword'].size()",
```

instead.